# Killing DB Query after timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, exception, timeout

[Java Spring-boot] I have an API that queries a database, and I wanted to make it so that if the query does not finish after 5 seconds, an exception is thrown. My current code looks like this.

```
@GetMapping("/return")
@Transactional(timeout = 5)
public List<TestEntity> findAll() throws InterruptedException {
    return testRepository.findAll();
}
```

This code, however does not time out after 5 seconds, because the timeout is only triggered AFTER each step is done, so for example, if return `testRepository.findAll();` takes 15 seconds to execute, then the code will only timeout 15 seconds (after that method is done). Is there any better annotation or method that allows me to throw an exception mid way through any method so that even if we are in the middle of `testRepository.findAll();`, the exception is still thrown the moment 5 seconds are up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout= 5000` to `applicaton.yml`